# Laravel dot files not being loaded (.env.local.php)

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, laravel-4

**What I'm doing:**

So, I'm using Laravel 4.0 (at least, that's where I started), I've since pulled in Laravel 4.2 via Composer. I've set up a `.env.local.php` file in the root of my project. I've confirmed that Laravel was detecting the `'local'` environment by using `dd(App::environment()`, but still the 'dot' files weren't being loaded. I know this, because it's saying that `$_ENV['DATABASE_NAME']` was not set in my config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it - and it was an embarrassingly easy fix.

**What I did to fix this:**

I followed the [Laravel instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) to upgrade Laravel 4.0 -> 4.1 -> 4.2, because what I didn't realise is that doing a `composer update` wasn't enough.

**Outcome:**

For whatever reason, `.env.local.php` was now being loaded - if someone has an explanation, what would be great! I hope that helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `.env.local.php` to `.local.env.php`

Comment: @user1153551 Although I don't think `.local.env.php` is correct this answer seems to be a valid answer. If `env.local.php` is supposed to be `.local.env.php` and this is why the file isn't being used, that would solve the problem stated in the question.

Comment: @user1153551 I think you meant to make this comment on Sirajul_Islam's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I's working with Laravel 4.2 the .env.local.php was working perfect for me.
and, with laravel 4.1, the .env.php works file.